# SQL output to Excel Errors

Tags: sql-server, excel, newline, carriage-return

How do I copy hundreds of lines of output from SQL query into individual lines in excel. To clarify each of my hundreds of lines have multiple new line breaks but I don't see those breaks when i do a select.

This is what the data looks like:

```
Description column in the table:

Hello world this is sample text
another line of text for example
and a third line example
```

however the data is really like this

```
Hello world <new line break> this is sample <new line break> text
another line of <new line break>  text for example
and a third <new line break> line example
```

when i try to copy this into excel i would like it to go into Column H (in my case) each of the lines should be in its own row.

```
row 1:     Hello world <new line break> this is sample <new line break> text
row 2:     another line of <new line break>  text for example
row 3:     and a third <new line break> line example
```

but because of the carriage returns this is what i'm getting

```
row 1:     Hello world
row 2:     this is sample 
row 3:     text
row 4:     another line of
row 5:     text for example
row 6:     and a third
row 7:     line example
```

if this was a singular column i would make this work, but as i mentioned this is column H I've got a bunch of columns before and after it that need to  line up.

Comment: Why not concatenate your SQL values into one string value for each row of data before you try moving it to Excel, then you won't have the linebreaks?

Comment: The thing is they are one field in the sql table - i'm not sure how to concatenate it because the field is called description: and the value for description is the whole line.

Comment: Couldn't you do a string replace of the new line characters in your SQL query so you don't have to worry about them?

Comment: What is the difference between the line breaks you want to respect and the ones you want to ignore?  Is one NL and the other LFCR?  In other words, how do you know that you want a new line after 'text' in row1, but don't want a new line after 'Hello world'?

Comment: And what is the datatype of the SQL Server 'description' column?

Comment: i did do a replace and changed them to a space for the data pull but i was more curious how to get them as they are with the line breaks into excel so that they appear on three lines but in one cell

Comment: @tysonwright varchar (255)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your SQL query, instead of replacing the line feeds within a field with spaces, replace them with:

```
   " & CHAR(10) & "
```

Have that column start with an equals sign and double quote, and end with double quote.  So, test data would output as

```
="Hello world" & CHAR(10) & "this is sample " & CHAR(10) & " text"
="another line of " & CHAR(10) & "  text for example"
="and a third " & CHAR(10) & " line example"
```

Put this into Excel. This will look like a mess, until you make sure that under Format Cells you've checked 'Wrap Text', then the carriage returns will appear within the cells.

Comment: So this doesn't seem to work because (even with word wrap turned on) each new line break is pushed into a new cell in the excel doc it's causing the same problem i have.

Comment: Hmm.  When I just did this (and I included other columns, all tab-delimited) it works as expected.  Can you try it with the sample output I have in my answer and see what happens?

Comment: I did pretty much that but I used "description" as the field and i used replace as the command to replace the char(13) with char(10) and its not working

Comment: Your SQL should something like this:  
CONCAT('="', REPLACE(t.description, <whatever the newline character in your database is>, '" & CHAR(10) & "'), '"')
FROM Table AS t
Is that what you've got?

Comment: i'm using ms sql server and i'm getting this message 'CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: If you're on an older version of SQL Server, they don't have CONCAT, so your code would have to be something like this: SELECT DescriptionForExcel = '="' + REPLACE(t.description, <whatever the newline character in your database is>, '" & CHAR(10) & "') + '"' FROM Table AS t

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165680/discussion-between-tysonwright-and-elizabeth).

Comment: I just moved our discussion to chat.